# ESP8266 HTTPS Get fails

Tags: https, get, arduino-esp8266

I'm tryin to connect to a site with HTTPS.
I wrote the code and the connection works. But the server replies me
the the file I'm loking for (a PHP file) has moved to https://...

The location is correct, but seems to me that ESP8266 sends the GET request without HTTPS, and only with HTTP.
Is it possible?
here is the server answer :

```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head>
> <title>301 Moved Permanently</title> </head><body> <h1>Moved
> Permanently</h1> <p>The document has moved <a
> href="https://mysite/myApp/nodmcu/selectParam_nodemcu_2.php?IdUte=57&amp;Campo=1">here</a>.</p>
> </body></html>
```

here the code :

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "MYWIFINET";
const char* password = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

const char* host = "mysite.org"; // only google.com not https://google.com

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  const int httpPort = 443; // 80 is for HTTP / 443 is for HTTPS!
  
  client.setInsecure(); // this is the magical line that makes everything work
  
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) { //works!
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  // We now create a URI for the request
  String url = "/Myapp/nodemcu/selectParam_nodemcu_2.php?IdUte=57&Campo=1";

  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
               
  Serial.println("request sent");
  while (client.connected()) 
  {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(line);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}
```

Comment: is the host in 301 response same as in host variable?

Comment: Yes. I changed here but is the same on my code